# How to add headers to email in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to add default headers to all emails in Laravel 5.1? I want all emails to be sent with the following header:

```
x-mailgun-native-send: true
```

Comment: where did you learn about `x-mailgun-native-send`? i can't seems to find any documentation on mailgun website. ta

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Laravel uses SwiftMailer for mail sending.

When you use Mail facade to send an email, you call send() method and define a callback:

```
\Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
    $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
});
```

Callback receives `$m` variable that is an `\Illuminate\Mail\Message` object, that has `getSwiftMessage()` method that returns `\Swift_Message` object which you can use to set headers:

```
$swiftMessage = $m->getSwiftMessage();

$headers = $swiftMessage->getHeaders();
$headers->addTextHeader('x-mailgun-native-send', 'true');
```

Comment: hi, i am having the same issue with some email domains not acceptable, @comcast.net mail domains keep failing as well as others.. i am using mailgun with my laravel setup. I am still having this issue even with the code so, hopefully you can answer some of my questions.

do you include the $headers in the Mail::send function() ? 
is there anything else needed? ports open? or anything i can check to make sure to get it working. 

any help would be great. Thankx

Comment: I can't get this to work. I keep getting `syntax error, unexpected '$swiftMessage' (T_VARIABLE)`. Thoughts?

Comment: @timpeterson that's most likely a parsing error, which means you have a syntax error in your code.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old post, but I'm passing by the same problem right now and I think this could be useful to others.

If you're using a structure exactly as shown in Laravel (6.x and 7.x), like this:

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('example@example.com')
                ->view('emails.orders.shipped');
}
```

you could add headers to the E-mail in the format below:

```
public function build()
{
   return $this->from('example@example.com')
                ->view('emails.orders.shipped')
                ->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
                    $message->getHeaders()
                        ->addTextHeader('Custom-Header', 'HeaderValue');
                });
}
```

I hope this could be useful.

link to the current documentation:https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#customizing-the-swiftmailer-message

Answer (score 7):

Slight modification to @maxim-lanin's answer. You can use it like this, fluently.

```
\Mail::send('email.view', ['user' => $user], function ($message) use ($user) {
    $message->to($user->email, $user->name)
        ->subject('your message')
        ->getSwiftMessage()
        ->getHeaders()
        ->addTextHeader('x-mailgun-native-send', 'true');
});
```

Comment: This looks really interesting: https://medium.com/@guysmilez/queuing-mailables-with-custom-headers-in-laravel-5-4-ab615f022f17

Answer (score 3):

For those who need to add this configuration to all emails (like me), there is a practical way using listeners.

1. Create a Listener:

`php artisan make:listener MessageSendingListener`

2. Add the following content to the `MessageSendingListener`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class MessageSendingListener
{
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(MessageSending $event)
    {
        $event->message
            ->getHeaders()
            ->addTextHeader('x-mailgun-native-send', 'true');
    }
}
```

3. Add the configuration to the application's event mapping array in `EventServiceProvider`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [

        // ...

        \Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending::class => [
            \App\Listeners\MessageSendingListener::class,
        ],

    ];
}
```

Obs.: Tested with Laravel 7.